# Different logins, but live session shared on two computers, what platform do I use and how would I build that?

Tags: javascript, php, encoding, computer-vision

I am trying to build a website that allows coordinators and teachers to be able to login with separate logins and see the same page at the same time on different computers (it is interactive). Do you know what platform we could use to do that? Any insight would be great!!

For example, a teacher would press a check next to a goal they think they met, and their coordinator would see that on their computer immediately, and press a checkbox and their side regarding whether they met the criteria.

Comment: Try out [Laravel](https://laravel.com/)

Comment: there are so many possibie ways to do that on so many different plattforms, that we cannot suggest something without know _all_ the requirements (server, database, distrubutability, maintainability, dev-time, react time - "immediately", ...). And it's off topic here on SO anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The platform could be any web server language. The javascript framework express.js which runs on node.js is very popular.

You'll need some javascript to send the goals to the server.

You'll need a database to store the goals. Mongodb is popular.

You'll need code to set and get the database goal objects into web layer goal objects.

You'll need a template engine to render the web layer goal objects as html and some more javascript to update all clients screens when a goal is checked.

Comment: Hi, I have a question. I have made the simple chat application using node.js and socket.io, but I do not know how to output the value of a checkbox on one page on both pages that are connected. The idea is similar to the chat, but I can not get it to work. Could you help?